# Непонятки с Post запросом

Tags: http, java

Здравствуйте.

Пишу небольшого бота для одного сайта и столкнулся с непонятной для меня проблемой,а именно:
Необходимо отправить такой вот запрос:

```
POST /account/knb/ HTTP/1.1
Host: goldenbirds.biz
Content-Length: 46
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: PHPSESSID=кука
summa=10&item=2&play_sub=%D1%EE%E7%E4%E0%F2%FC'
```

Пробую сделать так:

```
response=sendPostRequest("http://goldenbirds.biz/account/knb/","summa=10&item=2&play_sub=%D1%EE%E7%E4%E0%F2%FC",cookie,user_agent,"");
...
public static String sendPostRequest(String url, String parameters,
        String cookie, String user_agent, String header) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", user_agent);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(parameters.length()));
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

    Map<String, List<String>> ma2p = con.getRequestProperties();
    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(parameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine + "\n");
    }
    in.close();
    String resp = response.toString();
    String buf = "";
    Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();

    if (header.equals("")) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            buf += entry.getKey() + entry.getValue() + "\n";
        }
        buf += "\n";
    } else {
        return con.getHeaderField(header);
    }
    return buf + resp;
}
```

Вроде всё должно как по маслу,но что-то не так,ибо ответ не такой,как должен быть.

Прошу помощи.

Comment: Попробуйте Content-Length вручную не устанавливать, при пост запросе само должно установится. И вообше это величина в байтах. Засунув туда длину строки вы можете ошибиться, все зависит от кодировки.

Comment: Не помогло,к сожалению.

Comment: Возьмите fiddler, и пропустите свой запрос через него. Будет видно, правильно ли вы его отправляете.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал библиотеку от square - okhttp. Поможет вам избежать всяческих подводных камней, если вы далеки от этой темы + внутри себя кэширует, упорядочивает запросы и т.д.

Вот пример POST запроса

```
public static final MediaType JSON
= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```